# Wrong order of execution in Flutter asynchronous code

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, future

I am having problems with futures in a Flutter app.

```
void saveCats() async {
  var cats = await convertToCats(_rawData);
  await DatabaseProvider.db.addCats(cats);
}

Future<List<Cat>> convertToCats(CatList catData) async {
  var cats = <Cat>[];
  await catData.forEach(key, value) async {
    var pos = await calculatePos();
    print('This should come first');
    cats.add(Cat(name: key, pos: pos);
  }
}

Future<int> calculatePos() async {
  return await DatabaseProvider.db.calculatePos();
}
```

database.dart:

```
Future<void> addCats(List<Cat> cats) async {
  print('This should come second');
  // Do adding stuff here
}

Future<int> calculatePos() async {
  // Some code to calculate the position
  return pos;
}
```

In the above code, the `saveCats` function is called when a button is tapped. This function converts some raw data to a list of Cat models, and adds them to the database. As part of this conversion process, it calculates the `pos` of the cat in a list. My problem is that I would expect that, of my two `print` statements, the one in the `forEach` loop should come before the one in the `addCats` database function. But instead they appear in reverse order. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` often doesn't do what you expect, because the provided function runs as a closure.

It's more natural when you want to iterate over a list doing something to each element to use `for` (or one of the more functional type methods like `map`).

It's not clear what type `CatList` is, so this is approximate, but you'll want something more like:

```
Future<List<Cat>> convertToCats(CatList catData) async {
  var cats = <Cat>[];
  for (var i = 0; i < catData.length; i++) {
    var key = catData[i].key;
    var pos = await calculatePos();
    print('This should come first');
    cats.add(Cat(name: key, pos: pos));
  }
  return cats;
}
```

or

```
Future<List<Cat>> convertToCats(CatList catData) async {
  return catData.map(...some mapping function...).toList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't `async/await` in List.forEach() or Map.forEach() as both of them return void. 
Either use

```
await Future.forEach([1, 2, 3], (num) async {
    await asyncMethod(num);
  });
```

or something similar; 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/forEach.html